# Check if username appears in table

Tags: t-sql

So I have 2 tables
1 table User with columns Username(nvarchar) and Active(boolean)
and a second table UserCompany with column a Username(nvarchar) column.

I want to make all the Users from table one that dont exist in table 2 inactive.

Is there a way to do some kind of foreach from all the users and if the result comes out as NULL the user can be set as inactive? Searched online but coudn't find it.

Comment: Right answer - use foreign keys and create a relation between two tables instead of comparing the usernames.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code uses non-standard syntax). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using postgresql, oracle, sql-server, db2, ...

Comment: Sorry im using transact sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a condition in the `update`.  It looks something like this:

```
update users u
    set active = 0
    where not exists (select 1 from usercompany uc where uc.username = u.username);
```

If you want to *maintain* this over time, you will need `insert`, `update`, and `delete` triggers on `usercompany`.

Comment: Hello Gordon, this is what I was looking for. Thank you for the help. Will mark as resolved when it lets me.